# Stop SES from adding awstrack.me to all my email links

Tags: html-email, amazon-ses

Is it possible to prevent AWS SES from adding `awstrack.me` link to all my email links?
[Their documentation suggests](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/open-and-click-tracking-have-arrived/) that if I don't want a link tracked, I just have to add `ses:no-track` as a custom attribute, however, while this may prevent tracking, it still modifies the link.

Answer (score 5):

Open and click is an optional and configurable field in SES.
You have the Configuration set which you include in the email(as header etc) and SES understand if you want to insert open and click link. If you don't want, yon can just go to Configuration set and remove the checkbox for Open and Click.

Comment: It ended up being a a user error, `ses:no-track` works, I was updating my HTML templates but not updating the JSON before uploading.

Answer (score 4):

You now find it in your event destination where you specify what event types to receive, disable open and click tracking.

Not sure how to share a deep-link, probably not possible but the steps to get there are as follows:

1. Go to the
   [**SES Dashboard**](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses) (Simple Email Service)
2. Make sure you're in the right **region**!
3. In the left menu bar click on **Configuration sets**
4. Click on the **name** of the desired configuration set
5. At the top below the configuration set name click on **Event destinations*
6. Click on the name of the desired destination (in my case SNS)
7. Next to **Event types** click on **Edit**
8. Uncheck **Opens** & **Clicks** at the very bottom
9. **Save changes**
10. Make sure to **use** this Configuration set when sending mails

Just tested and it worked for me as expected

As mentioned by Jonathan Wareham here in the comments make sure you don't have "Virtual Deliverability Manager" with "Engagement tracking - opens and clicks" enabled as this would negate the former steps

Comment: Hi, I followed these steps to disable open/click tracking but I'm still getting the <img> tracker on every email sent out, and even if I don't use a configuration set.  Do you have any other suggestions as to why they persist?  Thanks.

Comment: hmm sorry just checked the raw email in gmail and there's only 1 <img> for my logo, no trackers. Make sure to follow all steps and from what I understand you NEED to actively use the configuration set otherwise it won't work. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, found this was due to me having enabled the SES 'Virtual Deliverability Manager' and within there is an option 'Engagement tracking - opens and clicks' which was ticked.  Once I disabled that, the tracking images stopped.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing, didn't know about that, going to mention that in my answer

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The bit at the end about Virtual Deliverability Manager was the key for me.